# Wordpress Category Content Slider

Tags: wordpress, plugins

On my website currently I have two different pages that I will also be creating categories for, with the same name. I would like to have two different content sliders, one pulling from each of the individual categories, so I can post articles and have them only show up in the slider of the relevant page. The plugins I've found for Wordpress so far only allow me to set up one slider that pulls from a category, not two.

What would be the best plugin (or hand coded solution) to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using slimbox plugin and combining it with http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/03.html